# Conditional Symbols not acting as intended

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, monogame

I'm working a c# monogame game and my code base consists of 3 Projects in my solution.

1. A shared portable library that contains all of my game engine code.
2. A monogame opengl cross platform project for all of my game play functionality
3. A monogame opengl cross platform project for my editor

My goal is to be able to use Conditional compilation symbols in my engine code (project 1.) to split up the engine code to allow me to determine if the current application is the game itself, or if Im currently in the editor(ie EDITOR or GAME so I can have #if EDITOR or #if GAME etc). I don't want to have an instance variable or a static variable in the actual code because I'd like to hide certain things from the actual game project.

My main issue is that if I define conditional symbols on my editor project it won't actually be defined in the code for my engine because the editor references the main game code which has a reference to the portable engine code on it. I can change the conditonal symbols in the game code project (1.) and those will be reflected in the engine code.

I've tried referencing the portable engine code directly in the editor project itself but that gets a slue of conflict errors because it's also referenced in the game code project.

What would be my best course of action to fix this issue?

*Here is my current reference set up*
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create 2 configurations for your editor and game.

> Build > Configuration Manager...

Configure different symbols and output positions.

Then use the batch build to build the 2 solutions individually.

> Build > Batch Build...